# Windows Phone project not showing on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition on my 32bit Windows 8 OS and also I have installed Windows SDK 7 and 7.1.1.

The problem is that even after installing phone development software my Visual Studio is not showing Windows Phone on my new project/template list. I tried reinstalling but it does not work but the Windows emulator is working fine.

Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this edition of Visual Studio: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-phone

Installing the SDK doesn't add the templates. You need to install the correct edition of Visual Studio and make sure that the Phone SDK is selected during the Visual Studio install.

Once installed, you'll want to make sure you have the latest SDK and emulators.

(I just helped someone at work with this issue yesterday).

Comment: Also, you will need to be running Windows 8 Pro to enable the emulators to run as they run as a Hyper-V virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this handy trick: Install a 64 bit OS then try to install visual studio. This somehow worked for me. Don't forget to update your SDK as well.
Always install the latest version of visual studio and include the phone sdk